# How do I convert this Pseudo C Code to VB?

Tags: vb.net, pseudocode

I have this pseudo code that I am struggling to convert to VB, any help would be appreciated.

record_buffer is a file of lines similar to this:
BU5|Delete|2__FMTRL000|20220413|20220503|
The objective is to get the checksum for all lines but the one provided is not the same as the one being generated

I also have these notes:

> The value of Checksum is defined according to the following sequence:
>
> - initialise to zero
> - consider each record in turn (including header but excluding trailer)
> - Break each record into four byte (character) sections (excluding the end of line character), padded with nulls if required, and exclusive OR (XOR) them into checksum.

```
num_chars = strlen(record_buffer)
For (i = 0; i < num_chars;)
   value = 0
   For (j = 0; j < 4; i++, j++)
       If i < num_chars Then
           value = ((value << 8) + record_buffer[i])
       Else
           value = value << 8
       End If
   ENDFOR
   checksum = checksum Xor value
ENDFOR
```

Here is what I have:

```vb
num_chars = recordbuffer.Length
For i As Integer = 0 To (num_chars - 1) Step 0
    value = 0
    For j As Integer = 0 To 3 Step 0
        If i < num_chars Then
            value = ((value << 8) + Asc(recordbuffer(i)))
        Else
            value = value << 8
        End If
        j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
    Next
    checksum = checksum Xor value
Next
Return checksum
```

Comment: Is there a problem with what you have?

Comment: I am not getting the same values from the function as what a 3rd party application is giving

Comment: Please give us sample input and desired output

Comment: Added some notes

Comment: This line I was not sure I had converted correctly: value = ((value << 8) + record_buffer[i])

Comment: That depends on what `record_buffer` is.

Comment: @GSerg If strlen is being used on record_buffer, record_buffer must be a null-terminated string.

Comment: Hi I cant paste sample as the checksum is unique to the file, and some of the data is sensitive but I have pasted some more info

Comment: In VB, you can convert a string into an array of `Char` (possibly via `IEnumerable.ToArray` which may require importing `System.Linq`).  Once you've done that, the C code should be straightforward to port to VB.

Comment: The `Step 0` on the loops is highly unusual but I think it should work.  It might be safer to write the loops as `While` loops though, it would end up a little closer to what a C-type `For` loop is transformed into.  I don't see anything obviously wrong with your VB code.

Comment: One issue is that in C, a char is an eight-bit ASCII value, while in VB.NET a Char is a 16-bit UCS-2 value. If record_buffer is a buffer of 8-bit ASCII characters, you might be better off treating it in VB.NET as an array of bytes.

Comment: You do not need to give sensitive information. For example, if recordbuffer is "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" what do you expect to get as the checksum?

Comment: Thats the problem, I have been given a file with a checksum already calculated, when I try and verify I get a different result